# View Item from List

Tags: search

So far, I've created a list and have crawled it and the list is searchable.
Now, when I click on a result (item in a list) it takes me to the DispForm of the list where I can view the data and/or edit it. However, when I click 'ok' it takes me to the actual list itself. I do not what that. I want to be taken back to my search results.

Is there a way to work around this? Like, can I create something similar to a profile page for BCS data to SEE the 'instance' (item) but not be taken to the actual file?

Hope I'm making sense. Thanks!

Pete

Answer (score 2):

If you customized the search results to include an "edit" link, and in that edit link include a "source" parameter in the query string of the URL. The source should be the URL you want to go back to when you click OK (in this case the search results). Now that is a simplistic description of a much more complex option, but it is one route to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

That's why the "back" button exists; not entirely sure why DispForm.aspx should care about which page the user navigated from to get there (or if the user pasted that url in the address bar)